# Sending the client certificate with the client hello to the server

Tags: tls, certificates

With client authentication the client sends the certificate after the client and server hello.

Is it possible to send it already with the client hello, so the server does not even answer with a hello but instead rejects the connection?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: This is not possible with a standard conforming implementation.

The [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) and [TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446) standards clearly describe the sequence of communication inside the TLS handshake. A client certificate can not be send inside the *ClientHello* since the structure of the *ClientHello* record does not have a place for it. It is instead sent within a *Certificate* record, similar to how server certificates are sent. Only a *Certificate* record from the client is supposed to be sent **only after the server explicitly requested it** with a *CertificateRequest*. (see TLS 1.3 spec, sections [CertificateRequest](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.3.2), and [Certificate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2) for the definition of this behavior)

Note that in order to prove that the client actually owns the certificate it needs to sign some challenge - and this signature (*CertificateVerify*) can be then checked by the server (see [CertificateVerify](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.3)). The challenge should not be set by the client itself since this would allow replay attacks. Therefore the challenge must at least in part be defined by the server - similar on how the same kind of challenge for the server certificate is partially defined by the client. To have this kind of input the client must have data from the server first, i.e. the *CertificateVerify* can not be send w/o an initial data exchange.

Even if the protocol allowed you to send a *Certificate* message along with your *ClientHello*, it would not save you round-trips on a successful handshake. This does not mean that the protocol could be designed in a way that the certificate is sent immediately but verified only later. This way the server could early reject a certificate which would be not acceptable no matter if the (later) validation failed or not. Only, the protocol is not designed this way. On reason might be that the server wants to notify the client which CA are acceptable so that the client can select the appropriate certificate. Other reason might be that using a valid but still wrong certificate is unlikely, so an optimization for this case is not actually needed.

Comment: Reasons for this choice? Wouldn't it be more efficient?

Comment: My guess: Client certificate is not always needed. So why send more data over the wire unless required?

Comment: @mait: see updated answer.

Comment: Would these challenge replay attacks still matter with the potentially upcoming encrypted client hello?

Comment: @mait: Yes, they would still matter. Letting the client fully decide on what gets signed makes it possible to replay such signatures - unless the server remembers all relevant signatures ever send to make sure that none got reused. And again, there are also other aspects (I've mentioned) why the client might want to have some information from the server before sending the certificate.

Comment: +1. Another reason to put Certificate later in handshake: TCP congestion window gets larger with each round-trip. As certificates can be fairly large, you want the cert as late in the protocol as possible to avoid packet fragmentation; network engineers consider it rude for the client to send a large amount of data before the server has had a chance to respond.